# Eucalyptus: Unable to run-instance > Error: ImageVerify! Failed Check

Tags: image, virtual-machine, eucalyptus

I have installed Euca 2.0.1 on Fedora 14. I have successfully manage to register my cluster, sc, nodes etc and uploaded/registered standard images.

I can already access the web portal; and manage configurations. All is good so far. Now when I try to create an instance I keep on getting this error for all of the EMI's in my image list..

```
euca-run-instances emi-B86C0FCF -t m1.xlarge
ImageVerify: Failed check! Invalidating registration: lab864/initrd.img-2.6.24-19-xen.manifest.xml
```

Here is the list of the images in the storage:

```
>>euca-describe-images
IMAGE   eki-D2A21029    lab864/vmlinuz-2.6.24-19-xen.manifest.xml   admin   available   public   x86_64 kernel   instance-store
IMAGE   emi-B86C0FCF    lab864/ubuntu.9-04.x86.img.manifest.xml admin   available   public   x86_64 machine  eri-059A1101   instance-store
IMAGE   eki-D2BA1030    lab864/vmlinuz-2.6.24-19-xen.manifest.xml   admin   available   public   x86_64 kernel   instance-store
IMAGE   emi-A7ED0F8A    lab864/centos.5-3.x86.img.manifest.xml  admin   available   public   x86_64 machine  eri-05C8110F   instance-store
IMAGE   emi-976D0F29    lab864/fedora.11.x86.img.manifest.xml   admin   available   public   x86_64 machine eki-D2BA1030    eri-05B21106    instance-store
IMAGE   eri-05B21106    lab864/initrd.img-2.6.24-19-xen.manifest.xml    admin   available   public x86_64   ramdisk  instance-store
IMAGE   eri-05861103    lab864/initrd.img-2.6.24-19-xen.manifest.xml    admin   available   public x86_64   ramdisk  instance-store
IMAGE   eri-05C8110F    lab864/initrd.img-2.6.24-19-xen.manifest.xml    admin   available   public x86_64   ramdisk  instance-store
IMAGE   eki-D2AC102E    lab864/vmlinuz-2.6.24-19-xen.manifest.xml   admin   available   public   x86_64 kernel   instance-store
IMAGE   eki-D292102A    lab864/vmlinuz-2.6.24-19-xen.manifest.xml   admin   available   public   x86_64 kernel   instance-store
IMAGE   eri-059A1101    lab864/initrd.img-2.6.24-19-xen.manifest.xml    admin   available   public x86_64   ramdisk  instance-store
IMAGE   emi-A1280F64    lab864/debian.5-0.x86.img.manifest.xml  admin   available   public   x86_64 machine  eri-05F11117   instance-store
IMAGE   eri-05F11117    lab864/initrd.img-2.6.24-19-xen.manifest.xml    admin   available   public x86_64   ramdisk  instance-store
IMAGE   eki-D2E9103A    lab864/vmlinuz-2.6.24-19-xen.manifest.xml   admin   available   public   x86_64 kernel   instance-store
```

I would appreciate if you could point me to some direction to fix this?

Thanks.
Omer

Updated:I have also tried creating the instance by providing the key (generated by euca-add-keypair) and also provided --kernel eki-xxxxxx and --ramdisk eri-xxxxx options; but the same errors shows up).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have many Images with the same name in the same bucket.  This is most probably the source of your error.

If I was you, I would try emptying Walrus completely and starting fresh with a different bucket name for each image trios (kernel, ramdisk, image).